# Pytest giving says module doesn't exist while script works fine otherwise

Tags: python, pytest

I wrote some unit tests for a function I'd created:

```py
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from bootstrap import Bootstrap

num = randint(5, 30)
array = np.random.rand(randint(5, 10), randint(2, 10))
boot = Bootstrap(array, num)
result = boot.create_bootstrap_array()

def test_length(result):
    assert len(result) == num
    
def test_equality(result):
    x = randint(0, num-1)
    assert len(result[x]) == len(result[x+1])

def test_shape(result):
    x = randint(0, num)
    assert result[x].shape == array.shape
```

The bootstrap module I'm importing is in the parent directory of the project and the directory is added to `PYTHONPATH` so it works fine if I just add a line at the end:

```
length_test(result)
```

At the same time when I try to run pytest from the command line I get the following error:

```
c:\python\rf_model\tests>pytest bootstrap_test.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.5.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: c:\python\rf_model\tests, inifile:
plugins: remotedata-0.2.1, openfiles-0.3.0, doctestplus-0.1.3, arraydiff-0.2
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting bootstrap_test.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module 'c:\python\rf_model\tests\bootstrap_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
bootstrap_test.py:10: in <module>
    from bootstrap import Bootstrap
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.18 seconds ===========================
```

I believe I correctly followed the [conventions for Python test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) when naming files and functions. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Do you get the same results when running `python -m pytest bootstrap_test.py`?

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Interestingly enough it seems to work fine if I move the test into the parent directory.